# Entity-Relationship Diagram for a scenario involving Books, Authors and Countries

Tags: database-design, erd

Certainly a noobish question, but I'll ask it anyway. Perhaps someone else will be thankful. ^^

I am getting warmed up with MySQL and I try to understand the concepts of creating well structured databases. Currently I am reading about Entity-Relationship Diagrams (ERD) and I asked myself:

If I have three tables which are linked by a forth one, for example: A book written by one ore more authors, and each authors and was published in one ore more countries.

```
authors          books            countries
id | name        id | book        id | publishedInCountry
 1 | ...          1 | ...          1 | ...
 1 | ...          2 | ...          2 | ...
 1 | ...          2 | ...          3 | ...
 4 | ...          1 | ...          3 | ...


linkTable
idOfAuthor | idOfBook   | idOfCountry
 1         | 1          | 1
...
```

How would an ERD look like for these ones?

**Additional information**

I thought of:

`[authors]` -- < is author of > -- `[books]` -- < was published in > `[countries]`

But how do I fit in the `linkTable`?

Comment: I'd advise you to start from Wikipedia's article on [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), continue to some on-line courses (like this one coming from University of Washington - [Principles of Database Systems](http://freevideolectures.com/Course/2833/CSEP-544-Principles-of-Database-Systems)), then continue with some [books on database design](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/needing-a-database-design-book). And in the mean time don't forget to look here, at questions with 'database-design' tag :-).

Comment: @Marian: Thank you for the links. They sound promising and I'll certainly go through them!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as far as I can see,

you need two separate link tables as these are unrelated, one for linking many books to many authors, and one for linking many countries to many books.

```
linkTable Author-Book
idOfAuthor | idOfBook  
 1         | 1          

linkTable2 Book-Country
 idOfBook   | idOfCountry
 1          | 1
```

Comment: +1 @Aufwind - goorj is making two assumptions, both probably valid: 1) you care about books that have more than one author, and 2) A book has the same authors in each country (ie translations are attributed to the original language author)

Comment: Hi, credits for pointing out my assumptions, which might not be valid. Adding the translator as author-per-country would complicate things. One solution could be to add the author link table between Book-Country and Author tables - to get a list of authors for every book-country combination. Another to use the link table as suggested by @Aufwind with Author-Book-Country, but with the Country ID taken to mean something like "if NULL valid for all countries", if set only for this country (i.e. translator(s))

Comment: Sorry for respondign that late, I simply forgot, that I asked a questin here. :-) @JackPDouglas: Thanks for pointing that out. @goorj: I assume ever book in my database is written in english. So there are no translations to consider. I must admit I have chosen a bad example. Perhaps one should exchange books by (science) papers and countrys by affiliations (and assume, that every paper is written in english). Would this afford 2 linking tables too?