# good practices of creating tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-recommendation, php

Hi I was thinking of developing an web apllication using php and mysql.
Application will give a professor the required data about the student.

i want to design application considering Engineering college.

So professor can view topper in perticular branch,overall topper in college,search student by roll no,display the list of students i roll no order or on the basis of percentage

Overalll data will consist of

Student name,roll no,year,percentage,department name,marks in each subject,subject name,branch

So please guide me to create table for the same in mysql..

thanks in anticipation

Comment: I'm closing this for the same reason it was closed on SO—it isn't a good fit for this Q&A format. I suggest you read up on the subject and come back with particular specific answerable questions.

Answer (score 1):

I once asked for answers to a problem very similar to yours, and even though I think back on how frustrated I was after a Software Architect did it to me, now, as a much wiser developer, I give the same answer to you.

> [Database Design for Mere Mortals: 2nd Edition
>   (2003)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201752840) by  Michael J. Hernandez. There is also a  [Database Design for Mere
>   Mortals: 3rd Edition
>   (2013)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321884493) by the same author.

-- Come back in a couple years as a database engineer, then give someone else the same answer.

Comment: @nikhil This question has also several good links: [Needing A Database Design Book](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/needing-a-database-design-book) Since you may already have some database theory book, I suggest the **SQL-Antipatterns** for some serious analysis of what **not to do** in a design (and also because the author works with MySQL mainly).